# Ошибка 404 при загрузке страницы Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Если запускать у себя проект через **ng serve**, то все работает нормально, но если я его билжу и выкладываю на github pages,то почему-то возникает следующая проблема - если я захожу на главную страницу, то все хорошо, но если я зайду потом на любую из вкладок, а потом нажму F5, то страница перезагружается с ошибкой 404, если я захочу сразу открыть вкладку, минуя главную страницу, то произойдет то же самое.

1. Ссылка на github: https://github.com/Drobovik04/KrRPI (исходник в
   dev)
2. Ссылка на github pages https://drobovik04.github.io/KrRPI/

Angular до этого никогда не использовал (да и с фреймворками фронта не работал), так что прошу простить, если вопрос глупый.